# Как написать функцию, которая возвращает строку в Си?

Tags: c, строки, функции, указатели

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работает моя функция `Change`? То есть я передаю туда строку, провожу манипуляции с массивом(?) и возвращаю строку как `char*`. Как это происходит? Почему нельзя указать тип возвращающего значения `char` и в аргументе `char * arr[]`? В моей теории я должен передать функции адрес строки и напрямую работать с ней.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* Change(char arr[], int n){
    
    //код

    }
    return arr;
}
int main(){
    int i=0;
    char str[20];
    gets(str);
    while(str[i]!=0){
        i++;
    }
    puts(Change(str, i));

    return 0;
}
```

---

В чем ошибка, если я напишу, например, так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char Change(char* arr[], int n){
    
    //код

    }
    return arr;
}
int main(){
    int i=0;
    char str[20];
    gets(str);
    while(str[i]!=0){
        i++;
    }
    puts(Change(str, i));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: char - это один символ. А Вы хотите возвратить строку, то есть массив символов.

Comment: `char* arr[]` - это указатель на массив символов. `char arr[]` и `char* arr` по факту обозначает одно и тоже, это оба указателя на начало массива. Массив - это ссылочный тип, что значит если вы передаёте его в функцию, то вы передаете ссылку(указатель) на него.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков например, во втором варианте кода(который неверный) одна из ошибок: [Error] cannot convert 'char*' to 'char**' for argument '1' to 'char Change(char**, int)' . Подскажите, почему char* ? Я ведь объявлял просто char, без звездочек. Да и в аргументе указал только лишь одну звездочку, вместо двух. Просто я провожу аналогию с объявлением int*, где у меня не возникает вопросов. Видимо так делать не стоит

Comment: @НаильУспанов у вас `char str[20]` и как я писал выше это эквивалентно записи `char* str = new char[20]` и вы пытаетесь передать `char*` в функцию где первый аргумент это `char* arr[]` что эквивалентно `char** arr` отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: @НаильУспанов только забыл добавить, что `char str[20]` это статический массив, а `char* str = new char[20]` динамический и после выделение памяти и работой с ней, должно следовать очищение памяти `delete[] str`. А при передачи в функцию это все является указателем на первый элемент. То есть `char*` надеюсь понятно объясняю

Comment: @ПавелЕриков `char* arr[]` - массив указателей, а не указатель на массив. *"`char arr[]` и `char* arr` ... это оба указателя на начало массива"* В параметрах функций первое заменяется на второе, да, но в общем случае это разные вещи. *"Массив - это ссылочный тип"* Ммм, мне кажется нет. В функции они передаются только по указателю/ссылке, да, но под определение [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) не подходят.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat для чего нужен массив указателей? то есть какое у него применение

Comment: @HolyBlackCat насчет первого, да ошибся немного. Насчет второго я описал сразу после этого комментария, что они эквивалентны при передаче в функцию. И третье ну массив всегда передается как указатель именно в c++ по этому я думаю его можно считать ссылочным типом, а в c# нужно объявить, что это ссылка на массив. Если я ничего не путаю конечно. Давно c# не занимался.